# Prove that $d(\vec{x} ,\vec {y})=0$ iff $\vec{x}=\vec{y}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Prove that $d(\vec{x} ,\vec {y})=0$ iff $\vec{x}=\vec{y}$

Note:$d(\vec{x} ,\vec {y})= ||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||$ and $\vec{y},\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$

---

My attempt:

Backwards direction (<=)

Supose $\vec{x}=\vec{y}$. Then
$$||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||= \sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+...(y_n-x_n)^2}$$

$$||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||= \sqrt{(y_1-y_1)^2+...(y_n-y_n)^2}$$

Clearly, $||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||=0$.

Forward direction (=>)

Suppose $||\vec{y}-\vec {x}||=0$. Then
$$||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||= \sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+...(y_n-x_n)^2}=0$$
$$=(\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+...(y_n-x_n)^2})^2=0^2$$
$$=(y_1-x_1)^2+...(y_n-x_n)^2=0$$
by series expansion,

$$(y_1-x_1)^2+...(y_n-x_n)^2=<y,y>-2<x,y>+<x,x>=0$$

Comment: If a sum of squares is zero, then all  the squares have to  be zero themselves, right?

Comment: are u saying that $<y,y>=0$ and $<x,x>=0$?

Comment: I am saying that $(y_1 - x_1)^2 = \ldots = (y_n-x_n)^2 = 0$, which means that $y_1 = x_1, y_2 = x_2 \ldots y_n = x_n$

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, all you  need is to show that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|x\|^2=0$ implies $x=0$. But if 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=0
$$
one must have $x_i=0$ for all $i$.